# Sonar Web Plugin

Tags: java, sonarqube

Can anyone point me in a direction to add custom profile rules for the sonarqube web plugin?

I've seen the xpath rules in javascript, but the web plugin does not contain anything like that.

Specifically, I'm trying to write some rules to check for WCAG2.0A compliance. The first rule I know I'm missing is checking for duplicate ids on the page.

If the web plugin doesn't support custom rules, can anyone provide a resource on how to build the plugin from source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible to add custom rules to the Web plugin.
Feel free to discuss the new rules that you would like to be added on the user mailing-list: user [at] sonar.codehaus.org.
To build it: mvn install

Answer (score 0):

**Templates** are available in the SonarQube web-plugin to create simple rules for HTML or JSP documents. Templates can be customized by user defined parameters. (This can be done in the SonarQube web interface and does not require any coding).

Available templates: *(in version sonar-web-plugin-2.6)*

- Track lack of required child elements
- Track lack of required parent elements
- Track presence of forbidden parent element
- Track uses of disallowed attributes
- Track uses of disallowed child elements

**Template Rule Example:**

- create a rule that checks that all *“area”* elements in the HTML document have an *“alt”* child element.

  1. Select the *“Track lack of required child elements”* template.
  2. Click on Custom Rules *“Create”* button.
  3. In the Custom Rule dialog enter a name and description for the new rule.
  4. Enter the parent element *“area”* and the child element “alt”.
  5. Save the rule.

[image: Create Custom Rule 1]
[image: Create Custom Rule 2]

To create rules that are not provided by the templates you'll need to modify the plugin source code (Java coding required).  See my other response.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a tutorial on adding a new rule *"empty-heading"* to the SonarQube web-plugin source code.  You’ll need to write some Java code.

TIP: Some simple rules can be created by customizing templates without any coding.  (see my first response)

### Example Rule:

- Name : *empty-heading* - Headings should not be empty
- Description: When at least one heading element (marked by <h1> through <h6>) is present, it is a best practice to ensure it contains content.
- Link: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/2.1/empty-heading

### Setup plugin:

1. Before you begin you will need Java 8, Maven 3 and Git installed on your box.  You will also need access to a SonarQube server.  You can download the server from here.
   https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/
2. Download the SonarQube web-plugin source code.

   **$ git clone https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-web.git**
3. Build plugin project with Maven.

   **$ mvn clean install**
4. Import the Maven project into an IDE for development.

### Add code to plugin:

1. Add the Rule class HeadingNotEmptyCheck.java to src/main/java

```java
/*
 * SonarSource :: Web :: Sonar Plugin
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2017 SonarSource SA and Matthijs Galesloot
 * sonarqube@googlegroups.com
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.coding;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.sonar.check.Rule;
import org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.AbstractPageCheck;
import org.sonar.plugins.web.node.Node;
import org.sonar.plugins.web.node.TagNode;
import org.sonar.plugins.web.node.TextNode;

@Rule(key = "HeadingNotEmptyCheck")
public class HeadingNotEmptyCheck extends AbstractPageCheck {

    private static final String[] headingTagsArray = StringUtils.split("H1,H2,H3,H4,H5,H6", ',');
    private TagNode startHeadingNode;
    private TextNode textNode;

    @Override
    public void startDocument(List<Node> nodes) {
        startHeadingNode = null;
        textNode = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(TagNode element) {
        if (isHeading(element)) {
            this.startHeadingNode = element;
            this.textNode = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(TagNode element) {
        if (isHeading(element)) {
            if (startHeadingNode == null || !startHeadingNode.getNodeName().equals(element.getNodeName())) {
                createViolation(element.getStartLinePosition(),
                        "The tag \"" + element.getNodeName() + "\" has no corresponding start tag.");
                this.textNode = null;
                return;
            }
            // found matching start tag for end tag
            startHeadingNode = null;

            if (textNode == null) {
                createViolation(element.getStartLinePosition(),
                        "The tag \"" + element.getNodeName() + "\" heading must not be empty.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(TextNode textNode) {
        if (!textNode.isBlank()) {
            this.textNode = textNode; 
        }
    }

    private boolean isHeading(TagNode node) {
        for (String headingTag : headingTagsArray) {
            if (node.equalsElementName(headingTag)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

2. Update CheckClasses.java to register the new rule class

```java
public final class CheckClasses {

  private static final List<Class> CLASSES = ImmutableList.of(
    ...,
    HeadingNotEmptyCheck.class,
    ...
```

3. Add HeadingNotEmptyCheck.html rule description to src/main/resources, org/sonar/l10n/web/rules/Web/ folder.

```
<p>When at least one heading element (marked by &lt;h1&gt; through &lt;h6&gt;) is present, it is a best practice to ensure it contains content.</p>
<h2>Noncompliant Code Example</h2>
<pre>
&lt;div&gt;
  &lt;h1&gt;&lt;/h1&gt; &lt;!-- Noncompliant; empty content --&gt;
  &lt;h2&gt;&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;!-- Noncompliant; empty content --&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
<h2>Compliant Solution</h2>
<pre>
&lt;div&gt;
  &lt;h1&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
  &lt;h2&gt;&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

4. Add HeadingNotEmptyCheck.json rule description to src/main/resources, org/sonar/l10n/web/rules/Web/ folder

```
{
  "title": "Headings must not be empty ",
  "type": "BUG",
  "status": "ready",
  "remediation": {
    "func": "Constant\/Issue",
    "constantCost": "2min"
  },
  "tags": [
    "accessibility",
    "bug"
  ],
  "defaultSeverity": "Minor"
}
```

5. Add JUnit test HeadingNotEmptyCheckTest.java to src/test/java

```java
/*
 * SonarSource :: Web :: Sonar Plugin
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2017 SonarSource SA and Matthijs Galesloot
 * sonarqube@googlegroups.com
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.coding;

import java.io.File;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.CheckMessagesVerifierRule;
import org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.TestHelper;
import org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.WebSourceCode;

public class HeadingNotEmptyCheckTest {
    @Rule
    public CheckMessagesVerifierRule checkMessagesVerifier = new CheckMessagesVerifierRule();

    @Test
    public void testRule() {
        HeadingNotEmptyCheck check = new HeadingNotEmptyCheck();

        WebSourceCode sourceCode = TestHelper.scan(new File("src/test/resources/checks/HeadingNotEmptyCheck.html"),
                check);

        checkMessagesVerifier.verify(sourceCode.getIssues()).next().atLine(8)
                .withMessage("The tag \"h1\" heading must not be empty.").next().atLine(12)
                .withMessage("The tag \"h2\" heading must not be empty.").next();
    }
}
```

6. Add test file HeadingNotEmptyCheck.html to src/test/resources, checks/ folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- invalid empty heading -->
    <h1></h1>
    <!-- valid heading -->
    <h1>h1 has content</h1>
    <!-- invalid empty heading -->
    <h2></h2>
    <!-- valid heading -->
    <h2>h2 has content</h2>
    <!-- invalid nested heading -->
    <h1>h1 has content
        <h2>h2 has content</h2>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

### Test and deploy the plugin:

1. Run the HeadingNotEmptyCheckTest JUnit test case.  If it works, you're ready to build and deploy the plugin.
2. Build plugin project with Maven.

   **$ mvn clean install**
3. Copy the plugin build artifact to the SonarQube plugin folder.

   GIT_REPO\sonar-web\sonar-web-plugin\target\sonar-web-plugin-[VERSION].jar -> \sonarqube-6.2\extensions\plugins
4. Restart the SonarQube server
5. Verify the new Rule on the SonarQube server

   Login to SonarQube, selects "Rules" menu, filter on Language "Web", you  should see the new rule "Headings must not be empty"

[image: new rule: Headings must not be empty]